# Is there a universal way to know if a user is logged in (or has authentication) to a website that works for all (or at least most website)?

Tags: javascript, authentication, cookies, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a browser (chrome and firefox) extension to download files from a database search engine (not exactly but something similar) to bulk download all the datasets that the user has selected. The problem is that these datasets are located at 6500 servers outside the search engine most of which require you to log in. So far I have tried to track the changes in the session cookie to determine the when to prompt login. However, this code fails when the user is already logged in because there is no change in the session cookie, and download isn't initiated. Can somebody suggest me a universal way to determine if the user is logged in or not?

This is the code snippet that I am using to check the cookies.

```
    const onLoggedIn = (getSingleLink, callback) => {

        let serverLink = getSingleLink();

        chrome.cookies.getAll({url:serverLink.split("/", 3).join("/") }, (cookies)=>{

            let baseLength = cookies.filter(cookie => cookie.session).length;

            if(
                baseLength >= cookies.filter(cookie => cookie.session).length ||
                cookies.some(cookie => (cookie.name.match(/_urs-gui_session/g)))
            ){

                const loginLink = serverLink.substring(0, serverLink.lastIndexOf("/"));
                loginWindow = window.open(loginLink, null, 'width=600,height=600');

                let loginInterval = setInterval(() =>{
                    chrome.cookies.getAll({url:serverLink.split("/", 3).join("/") }, (cookies)=>{
                        console.log(cookies);
                        if(
                            baseLength < cookies.filter(cookie => cookie.session).length &&
                            !cookies.some(cookie => (cookie.name.match(/_urs-gui_session/g)))
                        ){
                            loginWindow.close();
                            clearInterval(loginInterval);
                            callback();
                        }
                    })
                }, 500);

            }else{
                callback();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't, because different websites have different ways of identifying a user and their session, and this information can be kept hidden from the web-page, ergo it's impossible to handle this in all cases:

Some websites will use their server-side platform's session-state system and store the user's security-claims server-side referenced by their session-id (stored in a cookie), but both authenticated and unauthenticated users all have session-ids, so in this case it's impossible to tell (except of course, if there's a "Login" vs. "Logout" link or button rendered to the page).

Other websites, such as SPAs, may use OAuth/OIDC and store their `access_token` in `localStorage` rather than in a cookie and they'll add it to XHR/`fetch` requests as an additional HTTP header.

And in LAN environments, a webserver could use NTLM/Kerberos to secure itself, which can be integrated into the client operating-system (e.g. NTLM in IIS in a Windows Active Directory domain LAN with Internet Explorer) - in this case it's not possible to *not* be logged-in.